# How do I access unsupported UI elements?

Tags: delphi, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I want to test a Delphi application with Coded UI Tests, but I have some problems. I want access to some elements in the UI but cannot access all elements.

There is a list on the screen with some rows (according to the search parameters) and I want to access these rows to check the consistency of the values. But with the cross of Coded UI Test Builder I cannot access the rows on the application. How do I access the rows?

I just found one solution for now: Develop an extension for Coded UI Tests to interact properly with my Delphi application like [the sample on the Microsoft Web site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398055). It's an extension for Excel that allow you to access each cell. But it sounds difficult and the application I have to test is really complex as well.

Comment: You could always do a hack and output the values in the listbox to an invisible control. It would be a little more work to maintain but a lot quicker than developing an extension.

Answer (score 1):

If your interface is plain VCL, you can access most components by using their underneath `HWND` handle. It will work for `TEdit TMemo TComboBox TCheckBox` and so one. But some graphics components won't be able to be accessible from GDI messages, e.g. `TLabel` or `TGrid`.

So I guess you'll have to use a Delphi plug-in in your application, to let accessible the VCL components level. Use the `ComponentCount + Components[]` properties of a `TForm` (via recursive call) to access your component to be tested. Then publish its properties to the Coded UI Tests extension, which is to be written.

I speak about a "plug-in" here, because I do not think we may easily have access to all classes to be monitored / modified. Some "plug-in" architecture may help an application to work as usual, or in "Coded UI Tests mode", during testing phase. Perhaps better that a separated compilation for the purpose of tests: you should better test the final compiled executable. If you want only unit testing, you may recompile, stub and mock your application to only test a given form. But you'll need to code the form to be easily unit-tested (using dependency injection or such), which is far from easy in the default Delphi world (as with other RAD approaches).

Could be interesting to initiate an Open Source project (included with DUnit?) to develop such a platform. Or use an existing UI test framework for Delphi as base. A lot of companies we work in are mixing .Net and Delphi technologies, and would benefit for such a tool.

Comment: What exactly do I have to do in that plug-in ? Do you have some examples ?

Do you think that it could be possible to just code the extension without having some big changes in the Delphi Application ?

Comment: You could just run Synchronize over the Application current form, from a background thread, remotely accessible from your ui test framework.